# Lesbegue integration w.r.t scaled measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I was wondering if we have a measure $\mu$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda = a\mu$ if we get :
\begin{align}
\int fd\lambda = a\int fd\mu
\end{align}

It seems to work for the basic definition of lesbegue integral for simple function. Can we generalize to measurable function ?

Comment: This is just a thought: since you said it works for simple functions, for $f \geq 0$ measurable have you tried taking a monotonically increasing sequence of non-negative simple functions converging to $f$ and applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem?  It would look something like this:  $\int f \,d\lambda = \int \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} \,d\lambda = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int s_{n} \,d\lambda = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a \int s_{n} \,d\mu = a \int f \,d\mu$.

Comment: mmm So it would work also on measurable functions then ! That's interesting.

Comment: Well, so far it only works on non-negative measurable functions.  But it would be easy to generalize it to any measurable functions by the fact that we can decompose a measurable function $g$ into it's positive ($g^{+}$)and negative ($g^{-}$) parts, and the integral of $g$ is defined to be $\int g \,d\mu = \int g^{+} \,d\mu - \int g^{-} \,d\mu$.  Then apply the result to $g^{+}$ and $g^{-}$.

Comment: @user46944: Would you mind posting your comments as an answer?

Comment: Yes the answer is pretty complete and should be marked as such thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said it works for simple functions, now we consider $f \geq 0$ measurable.  You can find a monotonically increasing sequence of non-negative, measurable simple functions $\{s_{n} \}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} = f$.

Then, by applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem twice, we get:

$\int f \,d\lambda = \int \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} s_{n} \,d\lambda = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int s_{n} \,d\lambda = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a\int s_{n} \,d\mu = a \int f \,d\mu$.

Finally, to generalize this to any measurable function $g$, recognize that $g$ can be decomposed into $g^{+} -  g^{-}$, where $g^{+}$ is the positive part of $g$, and $g^{-}$ is the negative part of $g$.  Then, since $\int g \,d\lambda:= \int g^{+} \,d\lambda - \int g^{-} \,d\lambda$, you can apply the result to the nonnegative measurable functions $g^{+}$ and $g^{-}$ to get it for arbitrary measurable functions.